# Check if file path exists in a different node jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-api, hudson-api

Lets say I have 2 nodes:

- NodeA
- NodeB

I want to check if NodeB has a given directory through NodeA.
Is there a way to do this through the Jenkins API?

Expected Results

- NodeA should return true if the file path exists in NodeB
- NodeA should retrun false if the file path does not exist in NodeB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this.

```
def isDirAvailable() {
  def isAvailble = false;
  node('NodeA') {
     if(fileExists("/Path/to/dir")){
        isAvailble = true;
      }
  }
  return isAvailble;
}
```